# Tkinter button identification

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, button, window

I have created a list and made it so each item in the list creates a button called that item. I need to identify which button has been clicked but can't seem to find a way can anyone help. thanks

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("PC CONFIGURATOR")
window.geometry("1280x720")

def createNewWindowCPU():
    newWindow = tk.Toplevel(window)
    newWindow.geometry("1280x720")
    newWindow.title("CPU")
    AMD = tk.Button(newWindow, text = "AMD", pady = 10, width = 12, command=createNewWindowAMD)
    AMD.pack()

def createNewWindowAMD():
    newWindow = tk.Toplevel(window)
    newWindow.geometry("1280x720")
    newWindow.title("AMD")
    n = -1
    c = -1
    CPUF = ["Ryzen 9 5900x", "Ryzen 7 5800x", "Ryzen 5 5600x", "Ryzen 9 3900x", "Ryzen 7 3700x", "Ryzen 5 3600x"]
    def buttonClick():
        print(CPUBUT)
    for i in range(len(CPUF)):
        n = n + 1
        print(CPUF[n])
        CPUBUT = CPUF[n]
        CPU = tk.Button(newWindow, text = CPUBUT, pady = 10, width = 12, command = buttonClick)
        CPU.pack()

CPU = tk.Button(window,text = "CPU", pady = 10, width = 12, command=createNewWindowCPU)
CPU.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest and the easiest way would be to use the lambda function with the pressed button information already supplied.
I also applied optimizations no need to use range or n variable you were using

```
def createNewWindowAMD():
    newWindow = tk.Toplevel(window)
    newWindow.geometry("1280x720")
    newWindow.title("AMD")

    CPUF = ["Ryzen 9 5900x", "Ryzen 7 5800x", "Ryzen 5 5600x", "Ryzen 9 3900x", "Ryzen 7 3700x", "Ryzen 5 3600x"]
    
    def buttonClick(text):
        print('You clicked on ', text)
        
    for CPUBUT in CPUF:
        CPU = tk.Button(newWindow, text = CPUBUT, pady = 10, width = 12, command = lambda text=CPUBUT:buttonClick(text))
        CPU.pack()
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH. you've saved many braincells

Comment: mark the answer for the help of others when you think it solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achive what you want.

Approach 1 using event:

```
def buttonClick(event):
    button = event.widget#use event info
    print(button['text'])#cget text

CPU = tk.Button(newWindow, text = CPUBUT, pady = 10, width = 12)#delete command option
CPU.bind('<Button-1>',lambda e:buttonClick(e))#bind click event
```

Approach 2 using lambda to store predefined arguments:

```
CPU = tk.Button(newWindow, text = CPUBUT, pady = 10, width = 12,command=lambda info=CPUBUT:buttonClick(info))
```

Approach 3, using a dictonary:

```
def button_1_cmd():
    print(1)
(...)
CPUF = {"Ryzen 9 5900x":button_1_cmd,
            "Ryzen 7 5800x":button_2_cmd,
            "Ryzen 5 5600x":button_3_cmd,
            "Ryzen 9 3900x":button_4_cmd,
            "Ryzen 7 3700x":button_5_cmd,
            "Ryzen 5 3600x":button_6_cmd}
    
    for key,value in CPUF.items():
        b = tk.Button(newWindow,text = key,command=value)
        b.pack()
```